# mercurial convert and exclude files stored in store/data

Tags: mercurial

I have huge files stored under .hg/store/data and I want to convert the repo and exclude them. Files that saved only in history.

There is an option --filemap, but it requires "original" path to the file.
How can I know the original name and path of the file?

For example, what I have is:

```
.hg/store/data/_app/_cham/out-_p_k_g.d
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know the original name and path of the file?

Forget (for a long time) about repository (content of `.hg`) internals, work only with user-side representation, which is Working Directory (above `.hg`)

```
>dir /AD

07.07.2015  12:51    <DIR>          .
07.07.2015  12:51    <DIR>          ..
07.07.2015  12:50    <DIR>          .hg
09.03.2011  13:09    <DIR>          lang
28.08.2011  19:22    <DIR>          plugins
```

For simplest case just `hg up` in WD, get `/_app/_cham/out-_p_k_g.d` in working directory, define `path/to/file` for "exclude" command for `filemap`, add all other excluded files (or use one exclude for `/_app/_cham/`, if you'll prefer and can do it)